# Pinball loss metric to compare several probabilistic forecasts?

Tags: forecasting

For the first time, I am working with probabilistic forecasts, and want to confirm my approach is correct:

I have five different probabilistic forecasts predicting temperature at a specific location. Each of these forecasts outputs a value for each quantile from 0.01 to 0.99 at the same temporal resolution. Each forecast is generated slightly differently, and I would like to analyze performance based on the past few months of historical data (these forecasts have been running ~3 months).

When searching for a performance metric to compare these forecasts, Pinball loss seems to be appropriate, since it accounts for the asymmetric importance of errors (e.g., a forecast value higher than the observed value at the .95 quantile higher is a more significant error than a forecast value less than the real value at the .95 quantile).

My question is: What is the best way to analyze the entire forecast performance (considering all quantiles) and then compare the five different forecasts? Should I (for each FC) calculate the pinball loss for each quantile time then average the pinball loss values for each timestep?

Answer (score 1):

You need a probability scoring method such as Continuous Rank Probability Score. This can be interpreted as the average pinball loss over all quantiles (up to a scalar multiple). See https://otexts.com/fpp3/distaccuracy.html for further details.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to be the correct approach. I'm using Python, and I see there is a module "properscoring" for calculating CRPS (https://pypi.org/project/properscoring/). However, I don't see a clear way to calculate CRPS in my application. I see the function crps_ensamble(), but it states that the dimension of the forecasts should match the dimension of the observations. However, my observations are of course only one value for each timestep, whereas the forecast has a value at each quantile at each timestep.